# ShowcaseView with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, overlay, showcaseview

I found the great android library "ShowcaseView" to generate an "tutorial" view like in Android 4.0.
(https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView and http://espiandev.github.io/ShowcaseView/)

But I can't figure out how to use it with icons in my actionbar (I'm using ActionBarSherlock).

It should be compatible with the actionbar and ActionBarSherlock, but I can't access the ids.

With the actionbar icon in the left upper corner it works like charm...

```
scv = ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(android.R.id.home, this, "Hello", "My text", scvo);
```

And when I want to access a icon in the actionbar, no showcaseview is showing, even with the dev-branch.

Has anyone some ideas or experiences with this library?

Answer (score 2):

For showcasing ActionBar icons (also known as Action Items), you want to use the [`insertShowcaseViewWithType(ITEM_ACTION_ITEM, ...)`](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView/blob/master/library/src/com/github/espiandev/showcaseview/ShowcaseView.java#L734) method.

Comment: Thanks!
I see that this is only callable in the OnCreateOptionsMenu(), so the view is only shown when I press the icon, right?
So is there any way to call it in the OnCreate() function?
And would it be possible, when clicking the OK button, to generate a new view after that?

Comment: You should be able to call it in onCreate() fine. As for queueing ShowcaseViews, it'll be coming soon. Check this issue for more details: https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView/issues/37#issuecomment-17928478. Also, if you think I've answered the question, don't forget to mark it as answered!

Comment: The problem is, that I can't call it in onCreate(), not most of the time.
When I launch it on my Nexus S (CM 4.2.2), I get an "insertShowcaseViewWithType() must be called after or during onCreateOptionsmenu() of the host Activity".
And when I launch in on my Galaxy Tab 10.1 (4.0), it works like it shoud! Is there a problem with the 4.2 SDK?
Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, is this action item actually visible on the Nexus S? Only the first two ActionItems are visible on such a device (whereas the Tab can show 4). Failing that, please create a minimal project which shows the error, and we'll find a way to get in contact. Are you the person who messaged me on 12th May?

Comment: The item is actually visible, normally. But when I open the activity on my nexus (4.2.2), it crashes with the error. And when I open the activity with my galaxy tab (4.0) it works like it should...
And yeah I'm the guy ;-)
But thanks for the help!

Comment: Very weird! Basically, that error only happens when the ShowcaseView doesn't find that Action Item. I will email you to get more specific details about your error, then update this question once we've figured it out

Comment: @AlexCurran What about for `version 5.0`?

Comment: How do you do this in 5.0? Use an ActionItemTarget